# Rails 4 has_many through error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through, has-many

My 1st model:

```
class Author::SiteStorage < ActiveRecord::Base    
    has_many :author_site_storage_widgets, :class_name => 'Author::SiteStorageWidget'
    has_many :author_widgets, :class_name => 'Author::Widget', through: :author_site_storage_widgets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :author_site_storage_widgets, allow_destroy: true
end
```

My 2nd model:

```
class Author::Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :author_site_storage_widgets, :class_name => 'Author::SiteStorageWidget'
    has_many :author_site_storages, :class_name => 'Author::SiteStorage', through: :author_site_storage_widgets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :author_site_storage_widgets, allow_destroy: true
end
```

My :through model

```
class Author::SiteStorageWidget < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author_site_storage, :class_name => 'Author::SiteStorage'
    belongs_to :author_widget, :class_name => 'Author::Widget'
end
```

In rails console:

```
site = Author::SiteStorage.first
Author::SiteStorage Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "author_site_storages".* FROM "author_site_storages"  ORDER BY "author_site_storages"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Author::SiteStorage id: 1, uuid: "5fb9ffc0-b86d-0132-cdc5-0025bce6f338", key: "shared", content: "N4IgxgTgpghgLlAJgQTiAXARgCwCYDsAbAKy4CcAHIQAxUA0IA...", created_at: "2015-03-29 18:14:33", updated_at: "2015-03-29 20:38:34", site_type_id: 3, user_id: 1>

site.author_site_storage_widget_ids = [1,2]
Author::SiteStorageWidget Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "author_site_storage_widgets".* FROM "author_site_storage_widgets" WHERE "author_site_storage_widgets"."id" IN (1, 2)
```

This is the error I am getting

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Author::SiteStorageWidgets with 'id': (1, 2) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

Looks like missing inner join table

Comment: What happens when you grab for one author_site_storage_widget_id, rather than two? Also, in your first query, you use "site," but in the second you use "s." Is that intentional?

Comment: "s" mean site - fixed code